# issue with PHP spreadsheet reader

Tags: php, file-upload, spreadsheet

I am facing one issue with PHP spreadsheet reader https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader , it is reading all formats file except **.xlsx** , in case of .xlsx script was not running

```
require($docroot.'/inc/filereader/excel_reader2.php');
require($docroot.'/inc/SpreadsheetReader.inc.php');             
$Spreadsheet = new SpreadsheetReader("filepath");
```

When i am executing php script at my localhost, SpreadsheetReader reading .xlsx file and returning desired result, but when i am trying to run same code on some server then it is only executing for(.csv,.xls,.txt) but not for .xlsx.

I have already checked folder and file permissions for above issue at server.

What may be problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually **date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');** is not set in spreadsheet reader and it is throwing exception

Comment: Actually the date thing has been fixed since May 30, so this doesn't matter anymore in the newer versions.

Comment: Yes it has been fixed after I have raised this issue in front of pilsetnieks developer of nuovo/spreadsheet-reader.

Answer (score 0):

An xlsx file is actually a zip file containing the spreadsheet payload as a set of xml files.  This means that you need a php instance with the modules for zip and xml support loaded.  The easiest way to check whether the correct modules are loaded is by executing `phpinfo`, like this

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

If the correct modules are not loaded you will probably have to contact your webhoster.

Comment: would you please tell me the names of that modules

Comment: Zip  enabled ,
Extension Version  $Id: php_zip.c 300470 2010-06-15 18:48:33Z pajoye $,
Zip version  1.9.1,
Libzip version  0.9.0

Comment: i think Zip is enabled then why it is still not running

Comment: And what about xmlreader?  phpinfo should tell you whether it's enabled or not.  Once these preconditions are satisfied it would be very helpful to know whether the server gives some error info, the spreadsheetreader code is pretty big, it could fail for dozens of different reasons.  Is php configured to show all errors, or do you have access to its logfile?